# How to either change the date or get rid off it after using pd.to_datetime()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks as follows:

```
Datum   Dates   Time    Menge   day month
1/1/2018 0:00   2018-01-01  00:00:00    19.5    1   1
1/1/2018 0:15   2018-01-01  00:15:00    19.0    1   1
1/1/2018 0:30   2018-01-01  00:30:00    19.5    1   1
1/1/2018 0:45   2018-01-01  00:45:00    19.5    1   1
1/1/2018 1:00   2018-01-01  01:00:00    21.0    1   1
1/1/2018 1:15   2018-01-01  01:15:00    19.5    1   1
1/1/2018 1:30   2018-01-01  01:30:00    20.0    1   1
1/1/2018 1:45   2018-01-01  01:45:00    23.0    1   1
1/1/2018 2:00   2018-01-01  02:00:00    20.5    1   1
1/1/2018 2:15   2018-01-01  02:15:00    20.5    1   1
```

and their data types are:

```
Datum     object
Dates     object
Time      object
Menge    float64
day        int64
month      int64
dtype: object
```

I wanted to calculate a few things like the hourly average, daily average, monthly average and for that, I had to convert the types of the `Dates` and `Time` column. For that, I did:

```
data_nan_dropped['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data_nan_dropped.Dates)
data_nan_dropped.Time = pd.to_datetime(data_nan_dropped.Time, format='%H:%M:%S')
```

which converted my df to:

```
Datum   Dates   Time    Menge   day month
1/1/2018 0:00   2018-01-01 00:00:00 1900-01-01 00:00:00 19.5    1   1
1/1/2018 0:15   2018-01-01 00:00:00 1900-01-01 00:15:00 19.0    1   1
1/1/2018 0:30   2018-01-01 00:00:00 1900-01-01 00:30:00 19.5    1   1
1/1/2018 0:45   2018-01-01 00:00:00 1900-01-01 00:45:00 19.5    1   1
1/1/2018 1:00   2018-01-01 00:00:00 1900-01-01 01:00:00 21.0    1   1
1/1/2018 1:15   2018-01-01 00:00:00 1900-01-01 01:15:00 19.5    1   1
1/1/2018 1:30   2018-01-01 00:00:00 1900-01-01 01:30:00 20.0    1   1
1/1/2018 1:45   2018-01-01 00:00:00 1900-01-01 01:45:00 23.0    1   1
1/1/2018 2:00   2018-01-01 00:00:00 1900-01-01 02:00:00 20.5    1   1
1/1/2018 2:15   2018-01-01 00:00:00 1900-01-01 02:15:00 20.5    1   1
```

Now, in the `Time` column, the time is converted and has the form of 1900-01-01. I don't want that.

If possible, I would like one of the following:

1. The `Time` column be converted to `datetime64[ns]` without the date being displayed

or

2. The date that is in the `Datum` column be displyed there instead of
   1900-01-01.

How can I achieve this?

**Expected output:**

```
 Datum  Dates   Time    Menge   day month
    1/1/2018 0:00   2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 00:00:00 19.5    1   1
    1/1/2018 0:15   2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 00:15:00 19.0    1   1
    1/1/2018 0:30   2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 00:30:00 19.5    1   1
    1/1/2018 0:45   2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 00:45:00 19.5    1   1
    1/1/2018 1:00   2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 01:00:00 21.0    1   1
    1/1/2018 1:15   2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 01:15:00 19.5    1   1
    1/1/2018 1:30   2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 01:30:00 20.0    1   1
    1/1/2018 1:45   2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 01:45:00 23.0    1   1
    1/1/2018 2:00   2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 02:00:00 20.5    1   1
    1/1/2018 2:15   2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 02:15:00 20.5    1   1
```

Comment: The date is already in `Datum`, so what do you mean with _"The date that is in the Datum column be displyed there instead of 1900-01-01."_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly by looking at your expected output, we can use the `Datum` column to create the right `Time` column:

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

           Datum      Dates                Time  Menge  day  month
0  1/1/2018 0:00 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 00:00:00   19.5    1      1
1  1/1/2018 0:15 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 00:15:00   19.0    1      1
2  1/1/2018 0:30 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 00:30:00   19.5    1      1
3  1/1/2018 0:45 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 00:45:00   19.5    1      1
4  1/1/2018 1:00 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 01:00:00   21.0    1      1
5  1/1/2018 1:15 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 01:15:00   19.5    1      1
6  1/1/2018 1:30 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 01:30:00   20.0    1      1
7  1/1/2018 1:45 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 01:45:00   23.0    1      1
8  1/1/2018 2:00 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 02:00:00   20.5    1      1
9  1/1/2018 2:15 2018-01-01 2018-01-01 02:15:00   20.5    1      1
```